# How can I rename an already published app in the Windows Dev Center?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have an app that I have published to the Windows Store through the Windows Dev Center. I now want to rename that app. I have already followed the steps at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694077.aspx with no success. Things I have tried include:

- Reserved the new name
- Updated the app's manifest package display name in an app update
- Submitted the update for certification
- Passed certification and released to store

However, the old name remains displayed without the ability to remove the old reserved name.

I've tried asking this on the Windows Dev Center forums, but that place seems extremely dead.

Comment: The moderation team on MSDN's Publishing Windows Store apps forum is based in the US. Posts made in the middle of the night (US time) are likely not to get an immediate response, especially during holiday season. It looks like you received a couple of responses once day broke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing the right things. It can take a few days for a name change to propagate. If it still hasn't changed after 48 hours then please contact support at http://aka.ms/storesupport so somebody can check out your account.

Comment: Caplan Link is broken. I am also facing the same issue. Can you please help me with this? 
I have also followed the same steps given in question.

Answer (score 0):

The original link in the question is dead, but I found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/manage-app-names) while searching. This works for renaming the app when it is installed and running on your computer, but it does not rename the app in the Windows Store.

Eventually I discovered [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-app-store-listings) for renaming the app in the Windows Store by updating the "app Store listing." On the Submission page for the app in the Microsoft Partner Center, you have to click the language under Store listings. From here you can change which of your reserved names is used as the app name in the Store.